# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch

Tags: java, rest, authentication, hcl, wcs

In my project I need to migrate the login token of login user at the time of dev and uat environment cut over while we are upgrading the project into newer version.
So simply I have a separate project to migrate login token, we run the jar file of that project to migrate the login token. In that project we have simply 2 classes out of which 1 is for multithreading parallel processing and calling the another class in which we are hitting the token generate API and migrating the login token.

While I am running this jar file I am getting the "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!" for any random user not for all users.

This is my class to get the connection and to hit the token generate API

```
private void callGenerateTokenAPI(String memberId, String hostName) {
        final String methodName = "callGenerateTokenAPI";       
        String storeId = getUserContextStoreId(Long.valueOf(memberId)); // getting store id here
        String generateTokenURL = "https://"+hostName+"/wcs/resources/store/"+storeId+"/person/internal/tokens/byMember/" + memberId;
        LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, methodName, " URL: "+generateTokenURL+" with timeout :: "+this.timeOutInMs);
        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postSSLMethodCall(generateTokenURL , "POST" , this.timeOutInMs , headers);
        System.out.println( " completed for url : " + generateTokenURL);
    }
    
    private HttpURLConnection getSSLConnection(String generateTokenURL, String method, int timeOutInMs,Map<String, String> headers) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {      
        URL url = new URL(generateTokenURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeOutInMs);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeOutInMs);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : headers.entrySet()){
            connection.setRequestProperty(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public String postSSLMethodCall(String apiURL , String method , int timeout ,Map<String,String> headers)
    {
        final String methodName = "postSSLMethodCall";              
        String response = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;    
         try {
             connection = getSSLConnection(apiURL,method,timeout,headers);
            if(null!= connection){
                System.out.println(" Got connection , doing execution");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try{
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                }finally {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                }           
                response = sb.toString();
                LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, methodName, " response ==> " + response + " responseCode : " + connection.getResponseCode());
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              LOGGER.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASS_NAME, methodName, "Connection establishing Error for " + apiURL + " : is : "+e.getMessage());
          }finally{
              if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
              }
          }
        return response;    
    }
```